# MongoDB, C#. Update multiple array elements with different conditions

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

There is an entity with custom fields that can change their value. The fields are stored as an array.

```
public class SomeEntity :...
{
    ...
    public List<CustomField> FieldList { get; set; } = new List<CustomField>();
    ...
}
```

I use code like this to update one field:

```
var filterBuilder = Builders<SomeEntity>.Filter;
var updateFilter =
    filterBuilder.Eq(e => e.EntityId, entityToUpdate.EntityId)
    & filterBuilder.ElemMatch(e => e.FieldList, f => f.FieldId == updateField.FieldId);

var updateDef = Builders<SomeEntity>.Update.Set(e => e.FieldList[-1].Value, updateField.Value);

var updateRes = await GetEntityCollection().UpdateOneAsync(updateFilter, updateDef);
```

Sometimes it becomes necessary to update the values of several fields in the database at the same time, but I cannot find a way to do this in one action.

Is it possible in MongoDB to first search for a document using a filter, and then update/delete several elements of its array by their Id's (changes for each element may be different) in one action?

Is it possible to do the same for several documents (for example, remove fields with certain identifiers from all objects matching the filter)?

An example of an object **before the change**:

```
{
    ...
    "fieldList": [
        {
            "id": "3bf2c235-82c3-40e4-91dc-46dc4c1ed177",
            "type": 0,
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "id": "5909dabd-fe8f-4edb-a642-c052e23082d8",
            "type": 1,
            "value": "some value"
        },
        {
            "id": "66805403-d508-4b99-82f3-fa2ed828c19e",
            "type": 3,
            "value": "2019-08-01T12:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

An example of an object **after modification (only one document is updated)**:

```
{
    ...
    "fieldList": [
        {
            "id": "3bf2c235-82c3-40e4-91dc-46dc4c1ed177",
            "type": 0,
            "value": 500
        },
        {
            "id": "5909dabd-fe8f-4edb-a642-c052e23082d8",
            "type": 1,
            "value": "new value"
        },
        {
            "id": "66805403-d508-4b99-82f3-fa2ed828c19e",
            "type": 3,
            "value": "2020-09-10T10:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

An example of an object **after a massive change** (the document matched the filter, by analogy, all documents that would fit the filter should be updated - delete two fields, add a default value for some field):

```
{
    ...
    "fieldList": [
        {
            "id": "3bf2c235-82c3-40e4-91dc-46dc4c1ed177",
            "type": 0,
            "value": 500,
            "defaultValue": 150
        }
    ]
}
```